# Firebase sign in auth with google

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a sign in page using firebase and you basically use your google sign in option to log into the app. the problem is when the app is run on my computer it works. but doesn't work anywhere else when other developers try to run my same code. we figured out it may have something to do with the sha-1 key. when i remove that key and another developer add that key on the project from their machine, the app let them sign in perfectly. we want to make it so that anyone can log in without any problem when we run the code in other system.

Comment: Problem solved: We just had to make a global sha-1 key and have it saved in firebase

Answer (score 0):

For each developer machine,

SHA Key of debug keystore should be generated and added to firebase project settings page. It will allow for multiple SHA keys so no probs.

Finally when you publish your app to google play store, do not forget to add SHA key of your release keystore.

Comment: so does that mean when i create a signed apk , everyone will be able to run the app. and can i also create a signed apk file so the qa can test the app while it is in the building process because right now they won't be able to test anything because it won't let them sign in . the app is not finished yet so i wanna make sure if i sign it now , will it affect it because i'm still building it. thanks for your help.

Comment: I think, ideally you or your team member can deliver signed apk to QA team, it wont be a problem. so, you can add single SHA key of release keystore to firebase project which is much better than adding multiple SHA keys of debug keystores.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create one key for the project and add it to firebase and it allows everyone to access it. You don't have to add each one from every machine. It worked for me.